# How to ignore Socks4 when mitmproxy mode is Socks5

Tags: python, macos, firefox, socks, mitmproxy

When I'm running `MITMProxy` with `Socks5` mode and connections are coming from apps that use Socks4 (For example, `Firefox` in the default settings) then `MITMProxy` throws this error:

> SOCKS5 mode failure: SocksError('Invalid SOCKS version. Expected 0x05,
> got 0x4')

This behavior cause `Firefox` to return with "Unable to connect" error.
Is there an option to make `MITMProxy` ignore connections other than `Socks5`? (Modifying `Firefox` settings is not an option).

What I tried (With no luck) is to override `next_layer(...)` event in my addon but when Firefox sends requests this event is not raised.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore"? mitmproxy needs to determine the connection destination, so it does need to understand the proxying protocol.

Comment: I mean that if a non Socks5 connection is being made then the proxy should get it through to the internet without inspecting/changing it.
currently it's just throws error that it's non Socks5 connection.

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work. Where should mitmproxy send it to? It simply does not know.